# Why does flushing one toilet cause another to back up?

Tags: toilet

I have a problem with our toilets. when 1 flushed the first toilet, the "things' will came out the second toilet, which is the other side of the first toilet. This makes me have to flush both toilets to make it go away.

May I know why this happens?

Comment: I would suggest that you have a partial blockage of your sewer line, downstream of the toilets. When functioning properly (not restricted), there is nothing in the way of any material flowing downhill, down the path of least resistance, away from your toilets.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer that helped you the most, or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the 'airing pipe' is clogged or the sewer line is

Answer (score 0):

Back pressure might be cause by a block in your air vent.  If you see small vertical pipes in your roof, these are often sewer vents.  Sometimes birds or other debris can get stuck in them and clog them.  When that happens, the flow of air/gas is retarded and back pressure is not released in your system.

I have gone onto my roof with a hose and forced it down to unclog my air vent before.

Answer (score 0):

We had exactly the same issue and it was fixed in two parts. We found a cleanout that led from an entirely different place (kitchen sink) that was JAMMED clogged with grease where all the lines tied together. We also snaked the vents on the roof and founds some relief prior to finding that awful years old clog. Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

Yes I recommend a good sewer line cleaning, from a good rooter.

Comment: Hi, Paul. A one-line answer isn't really what we're looking for; a bit of explanation (why a sewer line cleaning) would be helpful.